# Android Native: How to deallocate object after returning from native layer

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I try to use native layer for allocating object. For example:

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL
Java_memory_hqt_com_heapsizetesting_jnitest_JNIActivity_getBigDataFromJni(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, jint memory) {

     unsigned char* buffer = (unsigned char*) malloc(memory);
     jobject directBuffer = (*env)->NewDirectByteBuffer(env, buffer, memory);
     return directBuffer;
}
```

And then I get again data at Java layer:

```
 public native Object getBigDataFromJni(int memory);
 ByteBuffer data = (ByteBuffer) getBigDataFromJni(1024);
```

As I know, native object isn't managed by Garbage Collector. So my question is: How can I reclaim memory after done with data object.

Comment: What's your rationale for creating a direct ByteBuffer in native code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for `free`ing the native buffer one simple approach would be to cast the `buffer` pointer to a `jlong`, return that to the Java layer as a Java long and later, when you are done, pass that back to the native layer, cast it back to a pointer and call `free()` with that pointer.

Note: I've never tried that on Android, but it usually works on Linux, diverse Unixes and Windows.